# How do I get values from an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array which is in the following format:

```
RBS: [  {
    "RegExp": "",
    "Type": ""
} ],
PAN: [ {
    "RegExp": "Date",
    "Type": "Date"
} ]
```

Now I want to pass the value `PAN` to a method and it should get the count of `PAN` length 1 and get `PAN` of regex values and type value. How can I do this? I formed an array like this: `Name` holds `RBS` and `PAN`:

```
var Regexp = [];
RegExpr.push(Name + ":" + Regexp);

function Check(test) {
    //test will be RBS /PAN
}
```

Comment: two things - 1) your array is not an array, it is an object (key-value thing, associative array), 2) In a object, a key cannot be repeated.

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {
  RBS:[{"RegExp":"","Type":""}],
  PAN:[{"RegExp":"Date","Type":"Date"}] 
};

function getTypeAndValue( obj, value )
{
  var output;
  var keys = Object.keys( obj );
  if ( obj [value ] )
  {
    output = obj[ value ][ 0 ];
  }
  return output;
}


var value = getTypeAndValue( obj, "PAN" );
if ( value )
{
  console.log( "type is " + value.Type + " and RegExp is  " + value.RegExp ); 
} 
else
{
   console.log( "this value doesn't exists" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

**HTML**

```
<div id="count"></div>
<div id="detail"></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var countEl = document.getElementById("count");
var detailEl = document.getElementById("detail");


function Check(test){
  var count = test.length;
  countEl.innerHTML = "Count: " + count;
  detailEl.innerHTML = "";

  for (var i = 0 ; i < count ; i++){
    var values = test[i];
    detailEl.innerHTML += 
      "<br/>" + (i +1) + ":<br/>" +
      "RegExp: " + values["RegExp"] + "<br/>" +
      "Type: " + values["Type"] + "<br/>";

  }

}

var Name = {
   RBS: [  {
    "RegExp": "",
    "Type": ""
   } ],
   PAN: [ {
    "RegExp": "Date",
    "Type": "Date"
   } ]
};
Check(Name.PAN);
```

**DEMO**

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0e20buba/).